# Can't use PHP session in 1and1 hosting

Tags: php, session, hosting

I've just bought hosting from 1and1 (german one) and I've got a problem. It seems like a session is not working in other files. When the user logs in, then nothing happens and I can see logged as: (empty) should be logged as test@mail.com. 
Why? 
The way I'm making session variables:

```
    session_start();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user where email = '$login'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(password_verify($password, $row["password"])) {
    if (!empty($row["email"]) and !empty($row["password"])) {
        $_SESSION["logged"] = $row["id"];
        $_SESSION["user"] = ''.$row["email"];
        header ("Location: panel.php");
    }

}
```

Everything goes fine because the user is redirected to panel.php
The way I'm calling session in navbar.php or panel.php

```
<?php
              session_start();

              if(isset($_SESSION["logged"])) echo '
               <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="panel.php">User Panel</a> </li>
               <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link text-primary" href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
              ';
              else echo '
              <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="login.php">Log in</a> </li>
              <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link text-primary" href="register.php">Register</a></li>
              ';
            ?>
```

On my university hosting it works as it should. Can some one advice me what to do?

Below I show phpinfo from 1and1 and my uni server:

[1and1server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZGxq.png)

[university hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leR3s.png)

Comment: Remove BOM from PHP file

Comment: What is BOM? Can you show me some example how to do it?

Comment: You can use notepad++ for this purpose https://notepadunix2dos.info/removebom.html